# ANdroid emulator does not show signal bars

Tags: android, networking, emulation

I have a problem with my android emulator. it does not shows network bars when i run it, instead it shows a cross over there.

The problem existed from the day i installed emulator.

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating avd once more and then play your application on new avd. The problem shud get resolved then.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
    I did it, but no success. Also APN settings are also not visible, it gives blank black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes internet disconnection makes the emulator network connection also disconnect,
close the emulator Clean Build and try launch emulator again.
hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Actually i discovered lots of reasons for this problem........ The scenario that you told is one of them.............. I agree.............. Thanks for answering.............

Answer (score 0):

Windows
DNS settings are specified in the TCP/IP Properties window for the selected network connection.

Example: Changing DNS server settings on Windows 10

Go to the Control Panel.
Click Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings.
Select the connection for which you want to configure Google Public DNS. For example:

To change the settings for an Ethernet connection, right-click the Ethernet interface and select Properties.
To change the settings for a wireless connection, right-click the Wi-Fi interface and select Properties.
If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Select the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) and then click Properties.

Click Advanced and select the DNS tab. If there are any DNS server IP addresses listed there, write them down for future reference, and remove them from this window.

Click OK.

Select Use the following DNS server addresses. If there are any IP addresses listed in the Preferred DNS server or Alternate DNS server, write them down for future reference.

Replace those addresses with the IP addresses of the Google DNS servers:

For IPv4: 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4.
For IPv6: 2001:4860:4860::8888 and/or 2001:4860:4860::8844.
For IPv6-only: you can use Google Public DNS64 instead of the IPv6 addresses in the previous point.
Test that your setup is working correctly; see Test your new settings.

Repeat the procedure for additional network connections you want to change.